# Trying to insert data into mysql table, but it all ends up in one column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert data from a tsv file into a mysql table. The data is formatted like this:

```
ID            rate    votes
tt0000004     6.4     98
```

It is to be inserted into a table formatted like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (ID VARCHAR(15), Average_Rating DOUBLE, Number_of_Votes INT, PRIMARY KEY(ID))
```

This is how I'm trying to insert it:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'ratingshort.tsv'
INTO TABLE db1.mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

However, when I view the table, it looks like this:

```
ID                            Average_Rating    Number_of_Votes
tt0000004     6.4     98      NULL              NULL
```

Does anyone know why it's only inserting itself into the first column and how I could fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it's a stupid question, but are you _certain_ that there are tab characters and not spaces between the columns in the source file?

Comment: Make sure you insert tabs between values, try that and give it a go.

Comment: OK so I double checked and it IS spaces, not tabs...is there a way to separate it based on spaces or a quick way to replace all the spaces with tabs?